# Triggers and ui sections subclassing View subclasses

Tags: javascript, marionette

I couldn't find a question about this subject although I guess someone would have faced this problem before. Excuse me if I'm re-posting.

I have a problem with a component I'm creating. Imagine component implemented as a ItemView that defines certain elements from it's UI as a "View.ui" hash.

What happens if I want to create an specialized version of that component by subclassing it and add extra ui element definitions? What I'm getting here is that new definitions overwrite the parent ones, so the parent functionality breaks.

Is there any common solution to workaround this issue?

The only one that comes to my mind is tweaking the "*.extend" functionality for base Marionette View class in order to treat specially these "ui" and "triggers" attributes when subclassing, using something more like a "*.merge" instead of a "_.extend".

Any other thoughts?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use _.extend in the inheriting objects constructor to merge the hashes.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/puleos/zkBCm/

```
var ParentView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    ui: {
        link : 'a',
        checkbox : "input[type=checkbox]"
    }
});

var ChildView = ParentView.extend({
    ui: {
        list : 'ul'
    },
    constructor: function(options) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);
        ParentView.prototype.constructor.apply(this, args);
        this.ui = _.extend(this.ui, ParentView.prototype.ui);
    }
});

var parentView = new ParentView();
var childView = new ChildView();

console.log('parent', parentView.ui); // Returns link & checkbox
console.log('child', childView.ui);   // Returns ul, link & checkbox
```

Comment: it's not a generic solution since I will have to add this behavior to all the subclasses that extend "ui" and "triggers" sections, but will work for now. Thanks for the suggestion Scott.

Answer (score 1):

Same as Scott's but I think it's a little more straight forward.  I dont see the point in rewriting the constructor function.  I was looking at constructor functions for each view type(ItemView, CompositeView, CollectionView), and they are each built differently.  So just stick the last line in the initialize function, and it should work across all views.

So like this.

```
initialize: function () {
    this.ui = _.extend(this.ui, ParentView.prototype.ui);
},
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is something more like this:

```js
var ParentView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    events: {
        'click @ui.link': 'onLinkClick'
    },

    ui: {
        link : 'a',
        checkbox : 'input[type=checkbox]'
    },

    onLinkClick: function () { ... }
});

var ChildView = ParentView.extend({
    events: _.extend({
       'click @ui.buttonStuff': 'onButtonStuffClick'
    }, ParentView.prototype.events),

    ui: _.extend({
        buttonStuff : 'button[data-action=do_stuff]'
    }, ParentView.prototype.ui),

    onButtonStuffClick: function () { ... }
});
```

Yes, you have to do it for every subclass, but the syntax is fairly compact.

I do this all the time with Backbone. I haven't yet tried it with any Marionette projects, but I can't see any reason why it wouldn't work.

This is similar to minijag's solution, but more efficient. Rather than extending the hashes every time the class is instantiated, it extends them precisely once, when the class is defined.